# Changing Legend Size with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, print-composer, legend

In QGIS, I use the python console to generate image files through the composer. In particular, I am creating a map with a legend. The legend is too big. It occupies about 1/8 of the image. I would like to make the legend smaller.

The code that adds the legend to the composition is:

```
c = QgsComposition(mapRenderer)
c.setPlotStyle(QgsComposition.Print)
cleg = QgsComposerLegend(c)
cleg.model().setLayerSet(mapRenderer.layerSet())
cleg.setItemPosition(0,45)
c.addItem(cleg)
```

A legend is created, but it is too big. In order to make it smaller, I have been reading the documentation of the QgsComposerLegend and QgsComposerItem classes, with no positive results. In particular, I have been trying to change the legend size by typing

```
cleg.setItemPosition(0,45,3,10)
```

but the size does not change.

I think I might have to make the font smaller first. If that is the case, I should use setStyleFont, which depends on a QgsComposerLegendStyle object which I don't know how to retrieve (I have tried to use the rstyle function, but I don't know how to use it).

In summary, could you please provide an example on how to:

1. Make the legend smaller
2. Make the legend font smaller?

Comment: In the composer window there is an option to word wrap on a particular character sequence.  I am afraid I am ignorant of the Python API (todo list) but you might see if the newline escape sequence '\n' could be inserted programmatically into your legend strings.  Or use a mesh of the composer and scripting to achieve a smaller width.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you guessed it's impossible to make the legend smaller then its contents. So, to change the legend font size, use something like:

```
newFont = QFont("Comic Sans MS", 6)
cleg.setStyleFont(QgsComposerLegendStyle.Title, newFont)
cleg.setStyleFont(QgsComposerLegendStyle.Subgroup, newFont)
cleg.setStyleFont(QgsComposerLegendStyle.SymbolLabel, newFont)
```

(depending on which component of the legend text you want to change). You may also want to adjust the symbol spacing, which can be done using code like:

```
cleg.rstyle(QgsComposerLegendStyle.Symbol).setMargin(QgsComposerLegendStyle.Top, 0)
```

Lastly, to adjust the symbol box size:

```
cleg.setSymbolHeight(2)
cleg.adjustBoxSize()
```

Using those three adjustments you should be able to reduce the size of your legend.

Comment: In PyQGIS 3, it would be `legend.setStyleFont(QgsLegendStyle.Title, QFont("Comic Sans MS", 6))`

Comment: Hi,  may i ask you how to modify the "layer legend" ? Insted of  .Title in QgsLegendStyle.Title, what should be used ? Is it  .SymbolLabel ou .Group ?